# How to pull data from a website without scraping

Tags: html

-Beginner here-
Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I need to pull some stats (not sort data) from this website: https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk. I just need those 4 main panels in a 2x4 table on my website.

How can I do this easily if possible?

The site updates regularly and I want to receive these updates in my page also.

I've looked into web scraping, but that's not what I need. I don't need to import or sort the data. I am taking the data that websites have formatted, and putting the main figures in my website for private use. (Just to reiterate, I would like to update on my website when they do on the one listed)

Again, I'm very new to this, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should use their API which is the intended way they provide to consume their information. They have a developer's guide with links to the APIs they provide.

https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/developers-guide

The only other way to go is by scraping. Which is less reliable (and tedious) because you depend on the website not changing their markup.